# Button disabling not working wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, datagrid

I am trying to disable a button from xaml if nothing is selected in datagrid but it's not working and I can't figure out why.

Here's my xaml code:

```
    <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="datagrid" ItemsSource="
     {Binding Path=Notes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
       IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    Margin="0,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="175" Width="300" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title"  Binding="{Binding Title}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Content" Binding="{Binding Content}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Edit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="218,9,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Height="25"
            Command="{Binding editCommand}">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=datagrid, Path=SelectedItem}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
        <Button.CommandParameter>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiCloner}">
                <Binding Path="SelectedItem" ElementName="datagrid"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Button.CommandParameter>
    </Button>
```

If anyone could help I'll appreciate it.

Edit: I'm using MVVM, so no code-behind.
Apparently first item in datagrid is always automatically selected and that's why button is always enabled but I still don't know what I did that make first item always selected.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it's "not working"? Have you confirmed that dataGrid.SelectedItem is in fact null?

Comment: Well I just checked it, even though I haven't clicked on anything somehow the first item is automatically always selected one. Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out. I just deleted

```
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
```

and everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your Button Command Binding may be interfering. The Command that the button is bound to has a CanExecute() function based on the ICommand interface. This automatically enables and disables the button depending on true/false return from CanExecute(). You can take the command out temporarily to see if that's the culprit - which I suspect it is. Then if you want to keep the Command, you can base the Command CanExecte() return value on datagrid SelectedItem != null, and you won't need the trigger for the button IsEnabled at all.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of having all those setter properties, try putting the stuff in the code-behind.

```
if (Nothing Selected In Datagrid)
{
Button1.IsEnabled = false;
}
else
{
Button1.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Also make sure to name the button and replace `Button1` with the name.

Comment: I'm using MVVM so I should't have anything in the code-behind.

Comment: I can't, MVVM is the assignment, it's not really my choice.

Comment: Are you in Visual Studio? What does intellisense say?

Comment: Yes I am, but I am still learning so I don't quite know what that is or how to use it.

Comment: Also I'm pretty sure you don't need the button.style element at all. You can remove the style.triggers as well.

Comment: There is nothing in error list, I can start program and do whatever I want but button is always enabled.

Comment: Remove all style elements and try it.

Comment: It's disabled only when datagrid is empty.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "selected" and "empty"?

Comment: When I click on any row, one item is selected and the button should be enabled, otherwise it should be disabled, when there is nothing in datagrid and when nothing is selected.

Comment: MVVM is just fine if you do it properly, which isn't at all difficult. I can't even imagine what you'd have to do to make it "unreliable"; more likely you're just making excuses not to learn something new.

Comment: @EdPlunkett do you actually have a solution or are you just here to make snide remarks?

Comment: OP resolved the issue. I was right, of course. The binding was fine.